# Zend_Db without Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I want using Zend_Db without Zend_Framework. I want incorporate Zend_Db for my existing website that was not made using Zend Framework. Is it possible to use Zend_Db like this? Can you recommend good tutorial or example how to do it good?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To some extent, this depends upon the web framework you are using. But, in general, the [Zend_Db documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.html) is pretty clear in this regard.

Create an adapter instance in your bootstrap. As an example:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

If you plan to use `Zend_Db_Table`, then you can make this the default adapter:

```
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

In any case, it's helpful to have this adapter saved someplace where you can access it. For example:

```
Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
```

Then in your downstream code, use this adapter to create queries for `select()`, `insert()`, `update()`, `delete()`, etc:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$select = $db->select()
    ->from('posts')
    ->where('cat_id = ?', $catId)
    ->order('date_posted DESC')
    ->limit(5);
$rows = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For Zend Framework 2.*, creating the adapter would be:

```
$db = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter([
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxx',
    'database' => 'test',
]);
```

To create select:

```
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($db);
$select = $sql->select()
    ->from('posts')
    ->where(array('cat_id' => $catId))
    ->order('date_posted DESC')
    ->limit(5);
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

Or, if you want to get pure SQL from the $select:

```
$selectSql = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
```

[Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html) might be helpful. It can be even simpler if [TableGateway](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html) is used.

Answer (score 0):

Using Zend_Db would even be preferable (IMHO) over using Raw PDO. Just create a $db Object and then create SQL Statements using Zend_Db_Select Class and pass the $select SQL Statement to the fetch* (fetchRow, fetchAll...) Methods.