# zend_db standalone

Tags: zend-db

i want to use zend_db standalone cos zend framework is too much for my project but i'm new with it,
is it correct to do this:

> $pdoParams = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES
>   UTF8;');
>
> ```
>     $params = array(
>         'host' => 'localhost',
>         'username' => 'ss_fraat',
>         'password' => 'jos10',
>         'dbname' => '_a2hDB',
>         'driver_options' => $pdoParams
>     );
>
>     try {
>         $db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
>         //set default adapter
>         Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
>     } catch (Exception $e) {
>         exit($e->getMessage());
>     }
>
>     //save Db in registry for later use
>     Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapter', $db);
> ```

then in any class do this:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
/** quote to avoid sql injection */
$date = $db->quote('1980-01-01');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = ' . $date;
$result = $db->query($sql);
$db->query(); //run a query
```

i really need to do this

```
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

i get this code from a website,
is it necessary to use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract if i'm not using the full zend framework,
or it is better for example to use this:

$db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);

what i want is to setup a pdo/mysql connexion in my bootstrap php page and be able to get that db instance in any class without starting a new connexion to execute queries but i'm not sure how to do that use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract or Zend_Db_Select use the registry Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapter', $db) or not 
thanks a lot

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840941/zend-db-without-zend-framework/4841608#4841608

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract is so you can create your own model classes based around the Table Data Gateway design pattern.  The idea of that pattern is that you have a class that encapsulates all the sql you would need for interfacing with a table.  So the assumption is that you will be creating model classes that extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract for each table.  If you are going to do that, then you will want to call Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db) in your setup/bootstrap.  Recent versions of ZF provide as an alternative a quick way of getting basic functionality without having to create a custom class definition by just instantiating Zend_Db_Table:

```
$userTable = new Zend_Db_Table('users');
```

In summary, none of this particularly has to do with the MVC part of the framework, although some people choose to use Zend_db as the basis for db connections and models, instead of using a more fully featured ORM like Doctrine or Propel.

The other code you provided simply illustrates that you do not need to use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract either -- you can simply setup an instance of a Zend_Db_Adapter and use that instance to call query() or its other methods.