# PHP - Select SQL Table using PHP variable in Select Statement

Tags: php, sql, variables, select

How can I use a variable to select the SQL table?

```
$sselect = $_GET['series'];
$episodes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM '$sselect'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use $\_GET inside mysqli\_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633600/how-to-use-get-inside-mysqli-query)

Comment: The table you query should **never** come from external input. Sounds like you should rethink your schema

Comment: @charlee I don't think that post is a good representation of what anyone should do

Comment: @Phil, Please elaborate

Comment: @CamAcc I have updated my answer to include what Phil is trying to say.

Comment: Your schema should be structured in a way that querying for records is based on the values stored in your tables, not the names of your schema objects.

Comment: @phil that answer gives a good example of using prepared statement if you look closely.

Comment: @charlee you can't bind schema object names though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
This should work. Thanks to @Phil he pointed out that table names should be enclosed in back-ticks. I have updated my answer to do that. The extra single quotes are used to complete the MYSQL query.

```
$sselect = $_GET['series'];
$episodes = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM `'.$sselect.'`') or die(mysqli_error());
```

**UPDATE:**

What Phil is saying is that if you use a $_GET variable someone can easily replace the URL with a different table name leaving a huge security risk. For example let's assume I have a table called `users` but I am expecting the `$_GET` variable to be one of the following: `cars`, `pencils`, or `colors`.

What you want is for the form to return an URL like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?series=pencils
```

But instead the user can change the data to represent this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?series=users
```

Allowing the user/attacker access into a confidential table. This is not a good practice and Phil was suggesting you change your schema as in your table structure so the user does not pick the table name.

Comment: MySQL uses backticks to quote schema object names (table / column names), not double-quotes ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @Phil Right, but my code like this still seems to work. I am not sure why?

Comment: @Phil Thanks I found the reason. It was because my code was not for object names rather it was for object values.

Comment: If you **must** accept the table name from `$_GET`, I'd at least create a whitelist of tables and make sure the value matches one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a simple concat?

`$sselect = $_GET['series'];
$episodes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ".$sselect) or die(mysqli_error());`