# php mysqli ajax jquery

Tags: php, forms, jquery, mysqli

i am creating a feed back page that allow users to give their feedback  and store this feedback in the database using php and mysqli  without refreshing the page using jquery and ajax but the problem is that i do not get any inserted data  although i get the success message 
if anyone can help me i will appreciate that

## feedback_form.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
  $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>feedback page</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    $(function(){

       $('#submit').click(function(){
         $('#container').append('<img src = "images/loading.gif" alt="Currently loading" id = "loading" />');


             var comments = $('#comments').val();


             $.ajax({

                url: 'feedback_process.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"comments": comments},

                success: function(result){
                     $('#response').remove();
                     $('#container').append('<p id = "response">' + result + '</p>');
                     $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function(){
                         $(this).remove();
                     });

                }

             });         

            return false;

       });


    });

    </script>




    </head>
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>


<body>
<form action = "feedback_form.php" method = "post">
<br />
<br />

  <div id = "container">
            <h2><?php echo $login_user ?></h2>



          <label for = "comments">Comments</label>
          <textarea rows = "5"cols = "35" name = "comments" id = "comments"></textarea>
          <br />
  </div>
   </form>
       <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "send feedBack" />



<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

## feedback_process.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        header("location:index.php");
    }


   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lam_el_chamel_db');

  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo"</pre>";

  if(isset($_POST['comments'])){

  $comments = $_POST['comments'];



  $query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text, user_name,) VALUES(?,?)";

  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  var_dump($stmt);

  if($stmt->prepare($query))
  {

     $stmt->bind_param('ss', $comments, $login_user);
     $stmt->execute();

  }
  $query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET feedback_text = ?, user_name = ? WHERE user_name = ? ";

  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query2))
  {
     $stmt->bind_param('sss', $comments, $login_user, $login_user);
     $stmt->execute();

  }



  if($stmt){

  echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon <br />";

  }
  else{
   echo "there was an error. try again later.";
   }  

}

else
   echo"it is a big error";
?>
```

table fields are : feedback_id feedback_text, user_name

Comment: you are saving data and returning a string, e.g. "thank you..". What are you meaning by "I do not get inserted data"? Do do not return anything like this, do you?

Comment: What is the value of `echo $stmt->error;` after your `$query2`

Comment: And: remove the var_dump, it might break the process :-D

Comment: @ jamie0726 the var dump is for track what is being send and visualize.....   second i do not get inserted data mean in the database no data are inserted

Comment: @ Hanky Panky  the value is    (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES(?,?)' at line 1thank you .we will be in touch soon ) how to solve this ???

Comment: @user2214618 remove the , after "user_name" in your query. :-D

Comment: Perhaps you're not committing the insert/updates? try adding `$stmt->close();` calls after each `$stmt->execute()`, and try closing the db connection, too

Comment: @  jamie0726  i did not quite understand you

Comment: `(feedback_text, username,)` should be `(feedback_text, username)`. The comma before the `)` is wrong.

Comment: thank you guys it was a silly error i had to remove a comma  thank you   jamie0726

Comment: What's the purpose of the `UPDATE` statement? You just inserted the same data right before it. If a user can submit multiple feedbacks, it will replace all of the old ones with the new text. And why do you set username if it's the same value?

Comment: I added the "solution" as an answer for further reference

Comment: @user2214618 final comment: consider using some kind of db layer, e.g. zend_db. It's easy to use (without the whole zend framework stack) and will give you many features out of the box like a proper centralized error management, it will help you avoiding sql injection etc. Check out this Stackoverflow post for a code example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840941/zend-db-without-zend-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra , in your query.

```
//old
$query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text, user_name,) VALUES(?,?)";

//new
$query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text, user_name) VALUES(?,?)";
```

Comment: guys i have a question a notice that if the same user enter another feedback  in the database it will insert a new row  but what i need is to just update the field of the feedback text without adding any new row for the same user

Comment: check out the replace command in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html

Comment: @ jamie0726 in the comments section   people say that if we use replace statement and we have the foreign key of this desired table  this table will be replaced and work well but the referenced table will be empty

Comment: @user2214618 you don't have a referenced table in your use case, don't you?

Comment: @user2214618 doing it like pouki06 recommended is also fine, though you have an additional query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a row exists with the same username :

```
//Check a row with same username exists 
$queryChecking = "Select COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE user_name = ?";
```

if the result is equal to one, you need to update row and not insert a new one ;)

Comment: @ pouki06  i am using the update statement but it seems that i am using in wrong way .. so you mean that before the insert statement i need to check  if username exist and then i  insert  or i update ??

Comment: yes. First check if an entry for the given user_name already exists. If not do an insert, otherwise do an update.

Comment: Yes exactly, like jamie said, if the row exist, reuse the same id returned by your check query, in this case update check query :

$queryChecking = "Select id FROM feedback WHERE user_name = ?"

if 1 row is returned, feedback already exists and you have to do update statement instead of an insert, else do the insert as you do now ;)